# Bad desc sorting performance for particular data - Postgresql 10.3

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sorting, postgresql-10

I have a question about a strange (?) case which I've found regarding sorting in
Postgresql (to be specific: 10.3).

I have a table `users` with the following columns:

- `id` - `varchar(36)` - id is in UUID format
- `firstname` - `varchar(255)`,
- `lastname` - `varchar(255)`.

The following indexes are created:

```
create unique index users_pkey on users (id);  
create index user_firstname on users (firstname);  
create index user_lastname on users (lastname);
```

Now, let's consider two queries for each data set.

1. I put into the table ~100k rows, where `firstname` is a random 10 char string.

   1a)

   ```
   select id, firstname from users order by firstname asc, id asc limit 50;
   ```

   and the execution plan for this query:

   ```
   Limit  (cost=7665.06..7665.18 rows=50 width=48) (actual time=105.012..105.016 rows=50 loops=1)
     ->  Sort  (cost=7665.06..7915.07 rows=100003 width=48) (actual time=105.012..105.014 rows=50 loops=1)
           Sort Key: firstname, id
           Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 31kB
           ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..4343.03 rows=100003 width=48) (actual time=0.009..21.510 rows=100003 loops=1)
   Planning time: 0.066 ms
   Execution time: 105.031 ms
   ```

   1b)

   ```
   select id, firstname from users order by firstname desc, id desc limit 50;
   ```

   a sorting is changed - desc instead of asc

   and the execution plan for this query:

   ```
   Limit  (cost=7665.06..7665.18 rows=50 width=48) (actual time=105.586..105.590 rows=50 loops=1)
     ->  Sort  (cost=7665.06..7915.07 rows=100003 width=48) (actual time=105.586..105.589 rows=50 loops=1)
           Sort Key: firstname DESC, id DESC
           Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 31kB
           ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..4343.03 rows=100003 width=48) (actual time=0.010..21.670 rows=100003 loops=1)
   Planning time: 0.068 ms
   Execution time: 105.606 ms
   ```

So far, so good. Sorting in both directions take a similar amount of time.

2. Let's consider second data set. I put into the table ~100k rows, where `firstname` is a string in the following format: JohnXXXXX, where XXXXX is a sequence of numbers, i.e. John00000, John00001, John00002, John00003, ..., John99998, John99999.

   2a)

   ```
   select id, firstname from users order by firstname asc, id asc limit 50;
   ```

   and the execution plan for this query:

   ```
   Limit  (cost=7665.06..7665.18 rows=50 width=43) (actual time=99.572..99.577 rows=50 loops=1)
     ->  Sort  (cost=7665.06..7915.07 rows=100003 width=43) (actual time=99.572..99.573 rows=50 loops=1)
           Sort Key: firstname, id
           Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB
           ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..4343.03 rows=100003 width=43) (actual time=0.009..23.660 rows=100003 loops=1)
   Planning time: 0.064 ms
   Execution time: 99.592 ms
   ```

   2b)

   ```
   select id, firstname from users order by firstname desc, id desc limit 50;
   ```

   a sorting is changed - desc instead of asc

   and the execution plan for this query:

   ```
   Limit  (cost=7665.06..7665.18 rows=50 width=43) (actual time=659.786..659.791 rows=50 loops=1)
     ->  Sort  (cost=7665.06..7915.07 rows=100003 width=43) (actual time=659.785..659.786 rows=50 loops=1)
           Sort Key: firstname DESC, id DESC
           Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
           ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..4343.03 rows=100003 width=43) (actual time=0.010..21.510 rows=100003 loops=1)
   Planning time: 0.066 ms
   Execution time: 659.804 ms
   ```

For second data set second query (`2b`) is 7x slower.

To sumarize:

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
| Query\Data set |     1      |      2     |
+----------------+------------+------------+
|  1             | 105.031 ms | 99.592 ms  |
|  2             | 105.606 ms | 659.804 ms |
+----------------+------------+------------+
```

And finally, my question.
Why is the second query for the second data set is 6-7x slower than the rest of the cases?

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebuilt the indexes after adding in the extra 50k of data? Check fragmentation.

Comment: Indexes are rebuilt.
The issues occurs on a new table with a new data so my assumption is that a fragmentation issue is not the case but to be sure, how can I check a fragmentation?

Comment: Go to your table ->indexes, right click on the index, select properties, then select fragmentation on the left menu of the tab.

Comment: What postgresql client do you use? I can't find this option neither in pgAdmin nor Intellij.

Comment: My sincerest apologies I thought you were using SSMS. In regards to this my colleagues found this article particularly useful: (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance#Index_Bloat)